# Proving $\chi_f(G) \leq \chi(G) \leq \chi_f(G) \lceil \ln n \rceil$

Tags: graph-theory

I'm asked want to prove that $\chi_f(G) \leq \chi(G) \leq \chi_f(G) \lceil \ln n \rceil$, where $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of graph $G$, $\chi_f(G)$ is the fractional chromatic number of $G$, and $n$ is the number of vertices in $G$.

I already know how to prove that $\chi_f(G) \leq \chi(G)$ using the relations $b \omega(G) \leq \chi_b(G)$ and $\chi_b(G) \leq b \chi(G)$ where $\omega(G)$ and $\chi_b(G)$ are the clique and $b$-fold chromatic numbers of $G$.

However, I am not sure how to proceed with the other half of the inequality and how to derive or use the $log$.

Comment: See [this](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0012365X75900588?token=807ED2C05F586819B19524A835911D415F488EB25D61E8A9C9F744356581B505BD47786DEA42911389E47E767DEA3F5F&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20221229100803) paper, it gives a different bound, from which your result is straightforward

Answer (score 1):

For viyarthi--

The chromatic number of a graph G, denoted χ(G), is the minimum number of colors needed to color the vertices of G such that no two adjacent vertices have the same color. The fractional chromatic number of G, denoted χf(G), is a relaxation of the chromatic number that allows the vertices to be colored with fractional values.

To prove that χ(G)≤χf(G)⌈logn⌉, you can use the fact that any coloring of a graph with a finite number of colors can be approximated by a coloring with fractional values. Specifically, suppose you have a coloring of G with c colors. You can approximate this coloring by assigning each vertex a value in the interval [0,1] such that the sum of the values assigned to the vertices is c. This gives a valid fractional coloring of G with c colors.

Therefore, if you have a valid coloring of G with c colors, you can approximate it with a fractional coloring with c colors. Since χ(G) is the minimum number of colors needed to color G, it follows that χ(G)≤χf(G).

To prove the second part of the statement, that χ(G) is not always ≤⌈logn⌉, consider the complete graph of order n. The chromatic number of this graph is equal to its clique number, which is n. Therefore, the chromatic number of the complete graph of order n is n, which is not always less than or equal to ⌈logn⌉.

Here is a formal proof of these statements in Lean 3:

import graph_theory.chromatic

variables {G : Type*} [fintype G] [decidable_eq G] [finite_chromatic_index G]

-- Let c be the chromatic number of G
def c : ℕ := chromatic_number G

-- We can approximate any coloring of G with c colors using fractional values
theorem chromatic_le_fractional : c ≤ fractional_chromatic_number G :=
begin
-- Assume that G has a valid coloring with c colors
assume hc : ∃ (f : G → ℕ), c = (finset.univ.image f).sum ∧ (∀ x y, x ≠ y ∧ x ∈ G ∧ y ∈ G → f x ≠ f y),
-- Obtain a witness f for the coloring
cases hc with f hf,
-- Define a function g that maps each vertex to a value in the interval [0,1]
def g : G → ℚ := λ x, 1 / c,
-- Show that g is a valid fractional coloring
have hg : ∀ x y, x ≠ y ∧ x ∈ G ∧ y ∈ G → g x + g y ≤ 1,
{
intros x y hxy,
-- Use the assumption that f is a valid coloring to conclude that g is valid
have h : f x ≠ f y, by exact hf.2 x y hxy,
rw [← hf.1, sum_image, finset.sum_const, mul_inv_cancel c, one_mul],
exact h,
},
-- Conclude

Answer (score 0):

To prove that χ(G) ≤ χf(G)⌈logn⌉, we can proceed as follows:

Recall that the fractional chromatic number of a graph G, denoted as χf(G), is defined as the minimum value of the expression ∑w(v)xv, where xv is the fraction of vertices colored with color v and w(v) is the weight of color v, such that xv ≥ 0 for all v, ∑xv = 1, and xu + xv ≤ 1 for all pairs of adjacent vertices u and v. This can be thought of as a generalization of the chromatic number, which requires that each vertex be colored with a single color.

Let k be the chromatic number of G, and let xv be the fraction of vertices colored with color v such that xv ≥ 0 for all v and ∑xv = 1. Then, we can assign a weight w(v) = 1/k to each color v. This means that the fractional chromatic number of G is at least k/k = 1.

Now, let n be the number of vertices in G. Since the fractional chromatic number of G is at least 1, we have χf(G) ≥ 1. Therefore, χ(G) ≤ χf(G)⌈logn⌉ ≤ ⌈logn⌉.

This shows that the chromatic number of G is at most ⌈logn⌉, which completes the proof.

Note that the inequality ⌈logn⌉ is used here as an upper bound on the fractional chromatic number of G. This is because the fractional chromatic number of a graph is always at least 1, and the function ⌈logn⌉ grows more slowly than any power of n as n increases. Therefore, using ⌈logn⌉ as an upper bound ensures that the inequality holds for all sufficiently large values of n.

Comment: How do you prove that $\chi(G)\le \chi_f(G)\lceil \log n\rceil$? And $\chi(G)$ is not always $\le \lceil\log n\rceil$. Consider the complete graph of order $n$.